# strange behavior with matplotlib plot.show

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to get a graph in which many by-products of a "parent" product are represented.
The code I use is the one below and the result is in the attached image. As you can see, from the end of the representation of the values of a product a straight line starts that joins the beginning of the values of the next product

```
def drawData(self):

        year = strftime('%Y')
        nbr= len(product_list)
        i = 0
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 30)
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
        data1 = \[\]
        lines1 = \[\]
        tick = \[\]
        nbrdate = 0
        while i <= lungh -1:
            name = productlist\[i\]
            query = "SELECT ...AND name = '%s' " % (name)
            nbr.execute(query)
            search = nbr.fetchall()
            for row in search:
                d_data = str(row\['data'\])
                month = d_data\[5:7\]
                giorno = d_data\[8:\]
                short = str(giorno + '.' + month)
                data1.append(short)
                value = row\['valore'\]
                lines1.append(value)
                if (nbrdate % 5 == 0):
                    tick.append(short)
                nbrdate += 1
            i += 1
            line, = ax.plot(data1, lines1)
            ax.set_xticks(tick)
            ax.set(title='This is a title')
            ax.grid()
            self.plotWidget = FigureCanvas(fig)

        lay.addWidget(self.plotWidget)][1]][1]
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Every time I encounter this problem it is because I have accidentally appended data for both x and y into two long lists/arrays and the line you are concerned about is matplotlib doing the sensible thing and connecting all the points.  I would try removing `line, = ax.plot(data1, lines1)` and putting `line, = ax.plot(short, value, '-m')` inside the `for row in search` loop.

Comment: @Finncent Price It only draws the x-y axis an the grid. No value inside

Comment: What does the `for row in search` loop look like now?

Comment: `for row in search:
                d_data = str(row['data'])
                month = d_data[5:7]
                giorno = d_data[8:]
                short = str(giorno + '.' + month)
                value = row['valore']
                
                line, = ax.plot(short, value, '-m')`  Removed the thick because, actually is not important

Comment: Ok, so now I think that problem is that FigureCanvas is using the line object to do the plotting and the last one in the loop is empty, so you are seeing nothing.  I don't know enough about Qt to try to help with that, though.  Sorry.

Comment: I really appreciate it. Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I deleted the layer by replacing it with a QMainWindow due to display problems. I assigned its values to each name, thus obtaining the individual lines to be passed to the plot. It's probably not the most technically sound solution, but it works

```
def drawData(self):

        year = strftime('%Y')
        nbr= len(product_list)
        i = 0
        nbrdate = 0
        while i <= lungh -1:
            name = productlist[i]
            query = "SELECT ...AND name = '%s' " % (name)
            nbr.execute(query)
            search = nbr.fetchall()
            data1 = []
            values = []
            tick = []
            for row in search:
                d_data = str(row['data'])
                month = d_data[5:7]
                giorno = d_data[8:]
                short = str(giorno + '.' + month)
                data1.append(short)
                value = row['valore']
                values.append(value)
                if (nbrdate % 5 == 0):
                    tick.append(short)
                nbrdate += 1
            if nome == 'AAAA':
                line1 = values
                legend1 = 'AAAA'
            if nome == 'BBBB':
                line2 = values
                legend2 = 'BBBB'
            ...
            i += 1
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
        line = ax.plot(data1, line1)
        line = ax.plot(data1, line2)
        ...
        ax.set_xticks(tick)
        ax.set(title='This is a title')
        ax.grid()
        plt.show()
```